# Get records from comma sperated list from same table

Tags: mysql

Table : Product

```
id | name       | related_product
---------------------------------
1  | Product 1  | 20,30,
2  | Product 2  | 200,300
20 | Product 20 | null
30 | Product 30 | null
200| Product 200| null
300| Product 300| null
```

Here, "related_product" belongs to same table "Product"..
Can you help me to write a query to return results like :

```
id | name       | related_product
---------------------------------
1  | Product 1  | Product 20,Product 30,
2  | Product 2  | Product 200,Product 300
20 | Product 20 | null
30 | Product 30 | null
200| Product 200| null
300| Product 300| null
```

So, basically I need product names instead product ids.

Comment: Storing values as csv in a table column is very bad db design. You should normalize your database. In the meantime you can use `find_in_set`

Comment: Yeah you are right, but can't help it now.. :(

Comment: find_in_set : can you help me to write a query with that ? I tried , didnt work for me

Comment: what is the max no.of product ids in related_product column

Comment: @Rams : maximum would be 5